# Cut string as pattern matching in shell

Tags: shell

I have a file test.txt which is having the content as:

```
P-SCALE2|S-HA1|S|P-SCALE1|P-SCALE3|Primary
```

from this file I want to get the output like :

```
P-SCALE2|P-SCALE1|P-SCALE3
```

it can be in any order.

Comment: Please, show us what you have tried.

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking: what is the pattern for this selection? And as @smartrahat said, what did you try?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$~) cat file.txt

P-SCALE2|S-HA1|S|P-SCALE1|P-SCALE3|Primary

$~) cat file.txt| awk -F"|" '{print $1"|"$4"|"$5}'

P-SCALE2|P-SCALE1|P-SCALE3

I hope this is what you wanted